# Intermittent screen corruption after boot

Tags: drivers, display, corruption

Running Arch Linux. Every now and then when it is booting (after a line has been selected in Grub), it will display some boot messages as normal, but then display something like this:

[image: Display showing corruption artifacts.]

I suspect it is a display driver issue, but it is odd that it only happens sometimes, and the rest of the time it boots correctly and the display works.

According to a sticker on the laptop, it has "Graphics by ATI Mobility Radeon X700".

Output of `lspci -k`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX480/RX482 Host Bridge (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS4xx PCI Express Port [ext gfx]
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 1
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 2
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller
        Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
        Kernel modules: ohci_pci
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller
        Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci
        Kernel modules: ohci_pci
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
        Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller (rev 81)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
        Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller (rev 80)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: pata_atiixp
        Kernel modules: pata_atiixp, pata_acpi, ata_generic
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
        Kernel modules: amd64_edac_mod
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
        Kernel driver in use: k8temp
        Kernel modules: k8temp
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV410/M26 [Mobility Radeon X700]
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: LSI Corporation ET-131x PCI-E Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: et131x
        Kernel modules: et131x
05:04.0 CardBus bridge: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ711MP1/MS1 MemoryCardBus Controller (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus
        Kernel modules: yenta_socket
05:04.2 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
        Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
        Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
05:04.3 Bridge: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/xD Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 0361
05:04.4 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394) (rev 02)
        Subsystem: O2 Micro, Inc. Firewire (IEEE 1394)
        Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
        Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
05:09.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT2500 Wireless 802.11bg (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Unknown 802.11g mini-PCI Adapter
        Kernel driver in use: rt2500pci
        Kernel modules: rt2500pci
```

Should I use a different driver?

Comment: I think it can be a memory problem, try to allocate different value of memory to the video card if that is possible on your hardware and clean the memory cards on the motherboard.

Comment: How would I do that? Note, this is a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

"**pci=nomsi**" kernel boot parameter seems to have solved the issue for me, after 15 reboots no screen corruption.Without it, sometimes i would get a corrupted screen at initialization or after resuming from screen powersave,the odds were around 1 corrupted boot for every 5-6 normal boots.

info

- laptop: acer 4100 travelmate
- gpu: ati mobility x700
- os: Debian 9 stretch
- gpu driver: mesa 13.0.6
- kernel: linux-4.9.82-i386 (compiled from source
  few irrelevant patches added)